# Ember.js - Cant filter my model based on today's date in nested route

Tags: javascript, ember.js, filter

I'm populating my model in the parent route with an AJAX call to my backend server, and everything works with that, but I'm trying to display only certain items based on today's date in a child route, but I'm having trouble.

Here's my router

```
Aplus.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('index', { path: '/'});
  this.resource('Dashboard', function() {
    this.resource('Agents', function() {
        this.resource('AllAgents');
    });
    this.resource('Jobs', function() {
        this.resource('AllJobs');
        this.resource('TodaysJobs');
        this.resource('NewJob');
    });
});
```

In the Jobs route, I'm populating the model, and I want to display a filtered version of the model in the TodaysJobs route

```
Aplus.JobsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var self = this; //otherwise will lose context of this in getJSON
    var jobObjects = [];

    Ember.$.getJSON('/jobs', function(jobs) {
      jobs.forEach(function(job) {
        jobObjects.pushObject(self.store.createRecord("job", job));
      });
    });
    return jobObjects;
  },
});
Aplus.TodaysJobsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('todaysJobs');
  }
});
```

This is what I have in the controller (nothing in the JobsController)

```
Aplus.TodaysJobsController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  filtered: function() {
    console.log(this.store.find('Job'));
    return this.store.find('Job').filteryBy('jobDate', '2015-2-7', true);
  }.property('Job'),
});
```

I'm unsure if I'm using Ember's property right, and when I run this I get an error saying cannot read property length of null.

This is what my template looks like:

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="jobs">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Job Date </th>
      <th> Customer Name </th>
      <th> Address </th>
      <th> City </th>
      <th> Phone Number </th>
      <th> Status </th>
      <th> Total Cost </th>
      <th> Notes </th>
      <th> Agent First Name </th>
      <th> Agent Last Name </th>
      <th> </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{#each job in filtered}}
      <tr>
        <td> {{job.jobDate}} </td>
        <td> {{job.customerName}} </td>
        <td> {{job.customerAddress}} </td>
        <td> {{job.customerCity}} </td>
        <td> {{job.customerPhoneNo}} </td>
        <td> {{job.status}} </td>
        <td> {{job.totalCost}} </td>
        <td> {{job.notes}} </td>
        <td> {{job.agentFirstname}} </td>
        <td> {{job.agentLastname}} </td>
        <td> <button class="btn btn-secondary">Edit</td>
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
  <tbody>
</table>
```

Any help would much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you using ember data? if you are do this in your jobs route, it's doing the same thing you are doing above with the forEach but delegating it to ember data conventions

```
model: function() {
    return this.store.find('job');
});
```

rename your model to use job instead of Job, ember follows camelcase conventions, it might do /Jobs if you don't change it on the AJAX call

and here do this

```
Aplus.TodaysJobsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('todaysJobs');
  },
  model: function() {
     return store.filter('job', function(job) {
          return Ember.isEqual(job.get('jobDate'), '2015-2-7');
     });
  }
});
```

update your controller to be an ArrayController and lose the filtered computed property

```
Aplus.TodaysJobsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({});
```

and your TodaysJob template should look like this

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="jobs">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Job Date </th>
      <th> Customer Name </th>
      <th> Address </th>
      <th> City </th>
      <th> Phone Number </th>
      <th> Status </th>
      <th> Total Cost </th>
      <th> Notes </th>
      <th> Agent First Name </th>
      <th> Agent Last Name </th>
      <th> </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{#each job in controller}}
      <tr>
        <td> {{job.jobDate}} </td>
        <td> {{job.customerName}} </td>
        <td> {{job.customerAddress}} </td>
        <td> {{job.customerCity}} </td>
        <td> {{job.customerPhoneNo}} </td>
        <td> {{job.status}} </td>
        <td> {{job.totalCost}} </td>
        <td> {{job.notes}} </td>
        <td> {{job.agentFirstname}} </td>
        <td> {{job.agentLastname}} </td>
        <td> <button class="btn btn-secondary">Edit</td>
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
  <tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yeah I'm using ember data, I'm not sure what you mean by your model function doing the same thing as the forEach. In my version, I'm creating a record in the store with the result from the backend route /jobs which calls a mysql query to get the job info from the database.

Comment: yeah so just doing store.find, hits that api endpoint, gets the results and puts each record in the the store for you, you don't have to explicitly call createRecord

Comment: Oh ok, yeah I changed it and that worked. Also, I tried creating the controller and doing {{each job in controller}} but that didn't show anything. What ended up working is taking out the controller and doing {{each job in model}} and now I get the desired results. Thanks a lot, much appreciated!